# Node.js issues retrieving data from cache

Tags: node.js

I save in redis cache some data, containg one field "planeId: "Floor.A".When I get from cache I have "planeId":"Floor.6479082"

Comment: You might want to show some code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us some more of what you have tried so far?

Comment: cacheResults: function(key, results) {
      this._cache.set(key, JSON.stringify(results));
    },                                                                                                                      getFromCache: function(key, params, evaluator, callback) {
      this._cache.get(key, function(err, value){
          var results = JSON.parse(value);
          var data = evaluator(results.visualization, params);
        }
        callback(data);
      });
    }